# Selecting node sets (attributes or elements) which match a string variable name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Consider this simple xml element example:

```
<parent foo="1" bar="2" foobar="3">
    <child/>
</parent>
```

In the xsl file, I am in the context of "parent" (i.e. within the <template match="parent">). I want to select a node set (in the example, only one attribute) based upon a string variable. For example i want to select a node-set which matches $attribute-name. I'll show my failed xsl example and you will probably understand what i'm trying to do.

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:call-template name="print-value-of">
        <xsl:with-param name="attribute-type" select="'foo'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="print-value-of">
    <xsl:param name="attribute-type"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$attribute-type"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This prints the output:

```
foo
```

What I first INTENDED it to do (but I realize that this is not what it should do) is:

1. evaluate the variable *attribute*-*type* (or param, if you want to be picky) as the string 'foo'
2. call the value-of as if I had called <xsl:value-of select="foo"/>

I.e. what I wanted it to print was:

```
1
```

**THE QUESTION**: How can I achieve this behaviour?

**Notice**: I am aware of the fact that I, in **this simple case**, could pass the actual attribute node as a parameter (i.e. <xsl:with-param name="attribute" select="foo"/>). But that is not the solution I am searching for. I need to pass only information about the attribute type (or attribute name if you'd prefer to call it that)

What I am actually trying to do is creating a general function template which can:

1. Call a function (call-template) with the attribute-type as a parameter
2. In the function do a bunch of operations which give me a node set, stored in a variable
3. sum all of the attributes of the elements in the node set, which are of the previously selected attribute-type

**<EDIT>**
I can only use XSLT 1.0, so 1.0 solutions are much preferred!
**</EDIT>**

**<EDIT2>**

**A follow-up question on a similar theme:** Is it also possible to create attributes of a with the name/type specified by a string variable? I.e.

```
<xsl:attribute name="$attribute-type"/>
```

Doing it like the line above results in $attribute-type being the literal name of the attribute in the xml output. Instead I would like it, again it to evaluate the variable and give the evaluated value as the name.
**</EDIT2>**

Comment: A comment to my latest edit (EDIT2): I noticed that the name attribute of the xsl:attribute element is specified as: name="attributename", while most other attributes of xsl elements are specified as e.g. select="expression". Maybe this means that it is not possible to create an attribute of with a name specified by a string variable, as I cannot use xpath in the attribute name? Am I correct?

Comment: It *is* possible. See my edited answer. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This selects an attribute with the name of `'foo'`.

```
<xsl:call-template name="print-value-of">
  <xsl:with-param name="attribute-type" select="@*[name() = 'foo']"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="print-value-of">
   <xsl:param name="attribute-type"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you can leave the `<xsl:call-template>` like it is and do the change in your template:

```
<xsl:template name="print-value-of">
  <xsl:param name="attribute-type"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = $attribute-type]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

In any case, unless this was only a synthetic example, all of the above is a quite expensive way of saying:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = $attribute-type]"/>
```

EDIT:

To create attributes with a dynamic name, use:

```
<xsl:attribute name="{$attribute-type}">
  <xsl:value-of select="$some-value-or-expression" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

Note that the curly braces make the XSLT-processor evaluate their contents (in attribute values only).

You should make sure that `$attribute-type` contains a string that adheres to the XML naming rules. And you should think about renaming the variable to `$attribute-name`, because *that's* what it is.

Comment: The last line of your answer is spot-on. That's exactly what I needed. I now however, ran into a new similar problem. I want to be able to create attributes with string variable names too (see EDIT tag in original question). Thanks!